# Modified tweepy stream class

Tags: python, google-sheets, tweepy, gspread

I have a project to practice my Python skills:

1. To extract some tweets coordinates with Tweepy Stream
2. To put them into a Google spreadsheet
3. Then use the Google spreadsheet to create a map in [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/)

I am already able to do all these things independently. Now, the challenge is to make everything work together! :)

To update my Google Spreadsheet, I am using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread).

However, to update a cell, I need to indicate the row and column of the cell like this:

```
worksheet.update_acell('B1', 'Bingo!')
```

I am trying to have a counter in my script extracting the tweets. The goal is to have B1 to change to B2, then B3, then B4, each time a tweet is found.

But it's not working... The coordinates are printed out on my Terminal, but that's it.

I guess I am not using the class as I am supposed to. But I don't understand where is my error!

Help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy
import gspread
import time

CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET = 'SECRET', 'SECRET'
USER_KEY, USER_SECRET = 'SECRET', 'SECRET'

class MyStream(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        tweepy.StreamListener.__init__(self)

        # I added this to have a counter.
        self.n = 2

    def on_status(self, tweet):
        try:
            longitude = str(tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0])
            latitude =  str(tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1])
            print longitude
            print latitude

            # I added this to update my google spreadsheet with the coordinates
            self.wks.update_acell(('A' + str(n)), longitude)
            self.wks.update_acell(('B' + str(n)), latitude)
            print "Spreadsheet updated!"

            # This is for my counter
            self.n += 1

        except:
            pass


def main():

    #I added these two lines to connect to my google spreadsheet
    gc = gspread.login('EMAIL', 'PASSWORD')
    wks = gc.open('SPREADSHEET_NAME').sheet1

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(USER_KEY, USER_SECRET)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStream(), timeout=50)
    stream.filter(locations=[-74.00,45.40,-73.41,45.72])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `str(self.n)`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

I just tried. Still the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble testing this myself (mostly because I'm not familiar with how `tweepy.Stream` works, I think), but it looks like your `MyStream` instance never gets its `wks` attribute set in the first place.

This means that when you refer to `self.wks`, it likely raises an `AttributeError`, but you never see it because of your `try`/`except` block. (Incidentally, this is why `except: pass` tends to be so hard to troubleshoot.)

You'll probably want to make `MyStream` take an additional `wks` argument, something like so:

```
def __init__(self, wks):
    tweepy.StreamListener.__init__(self)

    # Store the worksheet on this instance.
    self.wks = wks

    # I added this to have a counter.
    self.n = 2
```

And then change the line where you instantiate `MyStream` so you now pass that worksheet as an argument:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStream(wks), timeout=50)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Unfortunately, it's giving me the same result. :(

Comment: Can you remove the `try`/`except` lines in `on_status` and post what happens then? I assume there's an error being raised that would provide some useful information, but the `except: pass` part is throwing that information away.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer!

Actually, @jonrsharpe and @myersjustinc, you were both right!

"wks" wasn't properly set up and I wasn't using "self" correctly.

Thank you! Your hints helped me finding the answers!

EDIT: So here is the working code.

```
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamListener):
def __init__(self):
    tweepy.StreamListener.__init__(self)

    # I added self wks but also the login step on the same line
    self.wks = gspread.login('EMAIL', 'PASSWORD').open('SPREADSHEET').sheet1

    # I added this to have a counter.
    self.n = 2

def on_status(self, tweet):
    try:
        longitude = str(tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0])
        latitude =  str(tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1])
        print longitude
        print latitude

        # I added this to update my google spreadsheet with the coordinates
        self.wks.update_acell(('A' + str(self.n)), longitude)
        self.wks.update_acell(('B' + str(self.n)), latitude)
        print "Spreadsheet updated!"

        # This is for my counter
        self.n += 1
```

Comment: Oh! Okay. I am editing my post right one. Sorry! I am a Stackoverflow newbie! :)